# Changing colors in DirectShow

Tags: colors, directshow, rgb

I recently created my own DirectShow movie player as a control for use in WPF. This all works fine, but my customer would like a feature to boost colors depending on his preference.

Based on an old application he uses, he defines this as three seperate sliders, one for each color channel (RGB).

When R would be set to 255, and the others lower to zero, the red color in the playing video would be boosted, or at least "noticeably more red".

I have already messed with Hue, Saturation, Contrast, Brightness, all kinds of RGB to HSL/HSV calculations as found on wikipedia and such, but none of those really do what I expect.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Perhaps an exposed interface in DirectShow I missed, because I'm kind of clueless at the moment. Is it even possible by default in DirectShow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use oldskool directshow graphfilter interfaces?

IID_IAMVideoProcAmp:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
this interface has brightness, contrast, hue, saturation, sharpness, gamma etc.. setters and getters.

Transform Filter
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
This might not be click-click-it-works task if you create everything from scratch. Transformation filter is a capability to create intermediate filters changing video buffer pixels at runtime.

Do you use C#, C++ or other language?

You did say using Windows Presentation Framework(WPF), but then mediaplayer is a directshow application. My understanding is directshow is more or less dead tech.

Study WPF Effects interface, its a modern shader tech where you should easier transform pixel colors or whatnot effects be created.
[Pixel Shader Effect Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938514/pixel-shader-effect-examples)

**Edit** Few directshow filter related links for reference

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (list of MS directshow samples)
- http://en.verysource.com/code/4151972_1/ezrgb24.cpp.html (ezrgb24.cpp filter source)
- http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm
- http://mathinfo.univ-reims.fr/image/mmVideo/cours/DirectShow3Annexe.pdf

Comment: I ended up using the RGB DirectShow example filter, thanks for the pointer!