# Tinting an Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am trying to tint a `System.Windows.Controls.Image`. The image contains transparent areas and i'm just looking to tint the non transparent areas with a color.

For instance, the image is black/grey and tinting it red would result in a red gradient, with the transparent areas unaffected.

Is it possible to tint an Image in WPF either in XAML or the code behind (ideally) ?

Thank you

`<Image Name="OverlayImage" Canvas.ZIndex="2" />`

Example image:

[image]

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a `Rectangle` fitted over the image filled with the color you want and with an opacity of around `0.5`. Otherwise, you're going to need to either use a [custom WPF Effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341370(v=expression.40).aspx) or [edit the pixel data directly](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/106879/Set-Modify-pixels-in-a-BitmapImage).

Comment: Interesting. The problem is that these are full screen images, and are user contributed. Meaning that I don't know how tall/wide the non-transparent areas will be before hand. Pretty much ruling out the rectangle option :/

Comment: Not necessarily. When the image is supplied, you can do some math in the code behind to see where the image will be rendered. And there is actually a third option to use the image itself as the source for the `Rectangle`'s `OpacityMask`. See details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247010/tint-a-partially-transparent-image-in-wpf).

Comment: In the example you linked, the person is setting the width and height to specific values. My image is literally full screen. 1920x1080 in this case. If I implement the code you linked to in your previous comment, and set the width/height to full screen, will the transparent areas also be tinted?

Comment: No, because if the image is set to be the `OpacityMask` of the rectangle, the transparent areas will still be transparent. That's what an opacity mask does.

Comment: Aha, gotcha. Well i'll give that a shot then. I'l report back. Thanks

Comment: @Abion47 Your advice to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247010/tint-a-partially-transparent-image-in-wpf   Worked great. Can you change your comment to an answer please so I can mark it is the solution? Cheers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247010/tint-a-partially-transparent-image-in-wpf), you can use a `Rectangle` to do the tinting. Setting the source of the rectangle's `OpacityMask` to be the same as the image itself will take care of making sure the transparent bits stay transparent.

```
<Image
    Source="{Binding MyImage}"
    Width="150"
    Height="150" />
<Rectangle Width="150" Height="150">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MyImage}"/>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: How to change the `ImageBrush` programmatically?

Comment: This answer does not so much tint the image, because lighter and darker regions may (or probably) have same opacity. I went with GDI.

Answer (score 0):

A simple overlay won't do what you want.

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1656764/24874) a while ago. The consensus was that you could achieve this using pixel shaders. The answers on my question provide a few options.

Comment: All OP is doing is tinting all non-transparent pixels to a color. He isn't looking to preserve saturation or luminosity or anything like that, so a complex blending option with pixel shaders would be overkill.